# Are createTime and updateTime documentSnapshotFields to be discontinued on firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using the `FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot` fields `createtime` and `updateTime` on my nodeJS project, but now i find out that these fields are only part of [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentSnapshot#createTime), and can't be find at Firebase documentation for [DocumentSnapshoot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)

I am a bit confuse, are these fields new and are not yet on firebase documentation, or they will be removed as Firecloud is being Tailored from Google Cloud tools?

Comment: That second link is for JS client SDK. The API surface is slightly different there.

Comment: True, yet i look at [https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot] nodeJS client API and still there is no reference to those fields. The Admin sdk documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore for node JS doesn't have it either.